# Google Cloud ssh timeout: how to increase session time?

Tags: ssh, google-cloud-platform

For connection from Linux I use:

`gcloud compute --project "xxx" ssh --zone "europe-west-b" "yyy"`

After ~10 minutes of innactivity my console freeze or I see error `255`.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Google cloud has a session timeout across the board of 10 minutes, so you need to use a `keepalive`.  Try adding the argument `--ssh-flag="-ServerAliveInterval=30"` - any value less than 600 should do the trick there.

There's a description of the timeout [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting), and full usage details for gcloud ssh [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/ssh).

Comment: But how I can increase time from 10 minutes to 2 hours?

Comment: Why do you need to?  If you use a keep-alive your session should not die.

Comment: @IBam FYI, it should be `--ssh-flag="-ServerAliveInterval=30"`. Note the extra hyphen before `ServerAliveInterval`. Otherwise it's not passed to SSH as a flag, but as a host-string.

Comment: @IBam, additionally, I had to edit `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and set `TCPKeepAlive yes` (with `service ssh restart` afterwards, of course) in my gcloud vm instance with Debian GNU/Linux.

Comment: @NunoHenriques This shouldn't be needed.  From manpage: "It is important to note that use of server alive messages is very different from TCPKeepAlive".
It doesn't use the TCP keep alive packets. It is distinct, ssh-level.

Comment: @IBam Unfortunately, doesn't work for me. (OpenSSH_8.0p1 Ubuntu-6build1, OpenSSL 1.1.1c  28 May 2019)

Comment: Checked `/var/log/auth.log` on server and the server terminated the connection as client stopped responding. (About 6 mins.) 
Also checked in wireshark, if my ssh client really sends the alive packets and it does not (even with `--ssh-flag="-ServerAliveInterval=5"`)

So that needs to be fixed somehow.

Comment: What works for me is `--ssh-flag="-o ServerAliveInterval=5"`. (OpenSSH_8.0p1).
You have to use the additional options `-o` flag, as `-S` is a completely unrelated flag in OpenSSH, which when set to the rest (`erverAliveInterval=30`) did not produce an error!
@IBam you might want to edit the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It freezes because of KEEP_ALIVE. In Linux systems it's not started automatically.

You should run that command in the **linux client** or in the compute engine instance:

```
sudo /sbin/sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_time=60 net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_intvl=60 net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_probes=5
```

For MAC OS client:

```
sudo sysctl -w net.inet.tcp.always_keepalive=1 net.inet.tcp.keepidle=60000 net.inet.tcp.keepinit=60000 net.inet.tcp.keepintvl=60000
```

For Windows on the path:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\
```

Add these settings or change the values to:

```
KeepAliveInterval: 1000
KeepAliveTime: 60000
TcpMaxDataRetransmissions: 10
```

After that your client console will be able to keep a bigger session time !!!

Comment: How big is 'bigger' as I understand it is limited to max 10 mins

Comment: @ScottAnderson It will be higher than default time.